how to update magento 2.3.5p-1 to magento 2.4.3 the hard part is elasticsearch?
upgrade to magento2 2.3.5p-1 to magento2 2.4.3? the hard part is installing elastic search, i have, CentOS v7.9.2009 MariaDB 10.3 next version option to update is 10.5 and 10.6 if i update i can't downgrade at least if i re-install the whole operation system. any clean way that you can recommend me, i have 3 e-commerce website that i don't want to put them down for long.
i have tried it before but always errors.
